# How to set selected option through ng-options in angular dropdown?

Tags: angularjs

```
My code is like 

$scope.items = [{
"hospital_id":"hosp55121069e3cb0",
"hospital_name":"Sri Durga Clinic",
"locality":"Amasebail",
"speciality_name" : "Bone and Joint"
},
{
"hospital_id":"hosp55121069e3acd",
"hospital_name":"Apollo Clinic",
"locality":"Chennai",
"speciality_name" : "Cardiology"
}];
$scope.selectedHospital = null;
if(localStorage.getItem('selectedItem')) {
   $scope.selectedHospital = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('selectedItem'));

} else {
   $scope.selectedItem = $scope.items[1];
}
$scope.combined = function(item) {
     if (item.locality == undefined || item.locality == '') {
        return item.hospital_name;
     } else {
        return item.hospital_name + " " + item.speciality_name + " (" + item.locality + ")";
     }
}

$scope.update = function() {
        localStorage.setItem('selectedItem',  JSON.stringify($scope.selectedItem))

    }
```

When I set an selectedItem through localStorage value, its not selecting the  given value. But if i set it through $scope.items[index] it works.

My HTML is below:

```
<select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-change="update()" ng-options="combined(item) for item in items">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of `ng-options`, you can set the selectedItem using the object itself. Angular will set that appropriate item as selected. You need not mention a specific value.

So that's the reason why, when you use

```
$scope.selectedItem = $scope.items[index]
```

It works. Because the object is bound to the value of options.

When you're setting it via localStorage,

```
if(localStorage.getItem('selectedItem')) {
   $scope.selectedHospital = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('selectedItem'));

} else {
   $scope.selectedItem = $scope.items[1];
}
```

You're actually stringifying the object and storing it. So the object is not the same which was there before. You need to iterate through the list of items and find by matching the properties of that object.

Also notice, you are setting the value to `selectedHospital` and not to `selectedItem`. But in your `select` you are using `ng-model="selectedItem"` as the model.

Comment: But I am converting string JSON to JSON object so it should be same.

Comment: "You are setting the value to selectedHospital and not to selectedItem." It was a typo.

Comment: Angular keeps track of object based on reference. Once they are stringified, the reference is lost. So when you use JSON.parse, it creates new object and angular can't find it. Simple demo here: http://jsbin.com/ratejumalu/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: @SushantPrasad Hope you've checked the demo.